# how to use grep with logical operator AND

Tags: shell, grep, centos, yum

when searching for packages, i'm using `grep`, if not installed, i have to install it using shell script as mentioned below:

```
if 
    list packages installed | grep rap | grep rap-devel 
    ## only if both are installed then exit with status 0
else 
    install the missing packages
```

How should I do this?

I tried this but its very lengthy

```
yum installed packages | grep rap

if $? = 1
  yum install rap

yum installed packages | grep rap-devel

if $? = 1 
  yum install rap-devel
```

And I dont think its a good practice to do like this. Can anyone help me to shorten this? what if there still more to search and install

Comment: How can you do this with logical and?

Comment: `if $? = 1` attempts to execute the command `$? = 1`, which will almost certainly generate errors like `0: command not found`.  The `if` statement in the shell operates on a command.  If you want to know that `grep` succeeded, use `if grep ...`.  eg `if yum installed packages | grep -q rap; then ...`

Comment: But why are you doing this at all?  Just do `yum install rap-devel`, which will be a no-op if the package is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` and `||` operate:
`(yum installed packages | grep rap || yum install rap) && (yum installed packages | grep rap-devel || yum install rap-devel)`

for more search packages in the list:

```
pack_list=(rap rap-devel)
for i in "${pack_list[@]}"; do yum installed packages | grep rap || yum install rap; done
```

or if it could, you could use `which rap` instead of `yum installed packages | grep rap`.